# syncronized block inside static method will acquire Class level lock or Object level lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

in below code snippet, i have one question.
threads will acquire class level lock or Object level Lock ?

```
private static Object lock=new Object();
private static Object lock2=new Object();

public static void m1(){
synchronized(lock){
//statements
}
}

public static void m2(){
synchronized(lock2){
//statements
}
}
```

Comment: you have acquired lock on `lock` object. So it will have lock on that object not at class level

Comment: Thanks Ashish , i was confused ,whether Object class gets locked or object of Object gets Locked
in static methods , threads required Class level lock

Comment: It would use the `Class` object of the enclosing class only if the static method itself was synchronized or if you used `synchronized (EnclosingClass.class) { ... }`.

Comment: @Slaw  So here is my one doubt,Object is not related to static context then threads will acquire lock on Object, Or in my example it will aqcuire lock on "lock" Variable instead on Object

Comment: @Mohdshaban - See my answer below. Maybe it will help you clear your doubt

Comment: Thanks a lot guys both of you, now my confusion cleared

Comment: Refer to my ans. I have explain when you actually use Class itself as monitor object.

Comment: [17.1. Synchronization in this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object has a "monitor". When you use a synchronized block you specify the instance whose monitor you want to synchronize on. In addition to synchronized *blocks* there are also synchronized *methods*. A synchronized *instance* method will acquire the monitor of the instance the method was invoked on, whereas a synchronized *static* method will acquire the monitor of the `java.lang.Class` object of the enclosing class.

```java
public class Foo {

  private static final Object STATIC_LOCK = new Object();
  private final Object instanceLock = new Object();

  public static void bar() {
    synchronized (STATIC_LOCK) { // acquires monitor of "STATIC_LOCK" instance
      // guarded code
    }
  }

  public static synchronized void baz() { // acquires monitor of "Foo.class" instance
    // guarded code
  }

  public void qux() {
    synchronized (instanceLock) { // acquires monitor of "instanceLock" instance
      // guarded code
    }
  }

  public synchronized void quux() { // acquires monitor of "this" instance
    // guarded code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly used Object class instance as **monitor** object in you `synchronized` code block, which means it will take lock on those **objects** only.

A code block use Class itself as monitor object when you define a function as `static` and `synchronized` both. Because when you define a static function, that function belongs to class itself, means you don't need a class instance to invoke such functions. So if a static function is defined as `synchronized` then its execution in multithreaded environment will need to take a lock on some common monitor object among all such threads, which in such cases is `class` itself.

> Note - Every class definition itself is an instance of **java.lang.Class**